# BindingList hangs on ResetBindings call

Tags: c#, multithreading, bindinglist

I have a class which creates and updates a BindingList that is used as a binding source for a WinForms DataGridView. The form instantiates this class upon load. Then  the class (LotCache) creates the list with a type LotCacheItem.
It is updated every 20 seconds via a background worker thread. It executes the whole update of the list fine, but when I call "DisplayArray.ResetBindings()" it hangs, and never comes back. Below is the code for the class.
Is there an easier cross-thread implementation, am I doing something wrong?

```
    public class LotCache
{

    internal BackgroundWorker _fillPlantDataTable;
    private readonly DataGridView _frm;
    private Timer _gridRefresh;
    private BindingSource _source;


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lots dictionary, which holds the lots for the forms usage
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The lots dictionary.
    /// </value>
    public Dictionary<int, Lot> LotsDictionary { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The display array used by the Blood Pits data grid
    /// </summary>
    public BindingList<LotCacheItem> DisplayArray;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LotCache"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridView">The DataGridView that needs to be updated.</param>
    public LotCache(ref DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        _frm = dataGridView;
        DisplayArray = new BindingList<LotCacheItem>();
        DisplayArray.AllowNew = true;
        DisplayArray.AllowRemove = true;
        DisplayArray.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

        DisplayArray.ListChanged += DisplayListUpdated;
        _source = new BindingSource(DisplayArray, null);

        _fillPlantDataTable = new BackgroundWorker();
        _fillPlantDataTable.DoWork += FillDataTable;

        FillLocalDataTable();


    }
    private void FillLocalDataTable()
    {
        Get_ByHarvestDateLocal();

    }
    private void Get_ByHarvestDateLocal()
    {
        Lots _ls = new Lots();

        try
        {

            //This call gets lots from a local database
            DataTable _localLots = DataHelper.ExecuteProc("Local_LotCacheSelect", new ProcParams("HarvestDate", DateTime.Now));
            if (_localLots.Rows.Count > 0)
                DisplayArray.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow Row in _localLots.Rows)
            {
                Lot L = FillLots(Row);
                if (!_ls.ContainsKey(L.Lot_No))
                    _ls.Add(Row.Field<short>("Lot_No"), L);
            }

            LotsDictionary = _ls;
            StartGridRefresh();
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageWindow.Show("Network Error", e.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get all Lots by harvest date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="HarvestDate">The harvest date.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Lot" /></returns>
    private void StartGridRefresh()
    {
        int _refresh = 20;
        _gridRefresh = new Timer { Interval = _refresh * 1000 };
        _gridRefresh.Tick += GridRefresh_Tick;
        _gridRefresh.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void GridRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_fillPlantDataTable.IsBusy) //<------------This is always busy after first execution
            _fillPlantDataTable.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void FillDataTable(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Im in fillDataTable: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + DateTime.Now);
        try
        {


            DataTable _lotCacheTable = DataHelper.ExecuteProc("Local_LotCacheSelect", new ProcParams("HarvestDate", DateTime.Now));


            DisplayArray.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("Clear: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + DateTime.Now);
            DisplayArray.Clear();
            Debug.WriteLine("End Clear: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + DateTime.Now);
            foreach (DataRow Row in _lotCacheTable.Rows)
            {
                LotCacheItem _lc = new LotCacheItem();
                _lc.Lot_No = Row.Field<short>("Lot_No");
                _lc.HeadCount = Row.Field<int>("HeadCount");
                _lc.ProducerName = Row.Field<string>("Producername");
                _lc.BloodPittedCount = 0;

                DisplayArray.Add(_lc);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Grid Filled: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + DateTime.Now);
            DisplayArray.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;

            DisplayArray.ResetBindings(); //<--Never Finishes
            Debug.WriteLine("Bindings Reset: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " " + DateTime.Now);

        }
        catch (Exception _e)
        {
            //MessageWindow.Show("", _e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the LotCacheItem:

```
    public class LotCacheItem
{
    public int Lot_No { get; set; }
    public DateTime HarvestDate { get; set; }
    public int HeadCount { get; set; }
    public string ProducerName { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }

    public string Cool { get; set; }

    public string CustomHarvest { get; set; }

    public int BloodPittedCount { get; set; }


}
```

I hope I have provided enough information, if not, please let me know and I'll provide what I can...
Again, everything fills fine, but it never hits the debug write after the ResetBindings call in the FillLocalDataTable, causing the background worker to show as 'Busy' and never firing after initial load.